# Woocommerce - Custom MySQL Query - Get products with Multiple Taxonomies values

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I want to write a custom SQL query to get products (posts with post_type='product') with two specific values on two different taxonomies.

Basically, I want to get products that have a specific colour and belong to a specific category.

Both taxonomies can be found here:
[image]

- ***product_cat*** is the taxonomy for the category
- ***pa_colour*** is the taxonomy for the colour (which is a [product attribute](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/#attachment_156630))

Here is an example: I would like to get all products that have *green colour* and belong to the category *dresses*

I have tried different approaches. Let me walk you through it.

If I run:

```
SELECT
wp_vge8pp_posts.post_title, wp_term2.term_id
FROM wp_vge8pp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_relationships
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_vge8pp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy wp_tax1
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_tax1.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_tax1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy wp_tax2
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_tax2.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_tax2.taxonomy = 'pa_colour'
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term1
ON wp_tax1.term_id = wp_term1.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term2
ON wp_tax2.term_id = wp_term2.term_id
WHERE wp_vge8pp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND wp_vge8pp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_term2.name = 'green' /* GREEN COLOUR */
```

I get all the products that have the attribute pa_colour = green, and that is the correct outcome.

Then if I run:

```
SELECT
wp_vge8pp_posts.post_title, wp_term2.term_id
FROM wp_vge8pp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_relationships
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_vge8pp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy wp_tax1
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_tax1.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_tax1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy wp_tax2
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_tax2.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_tax2.taxonomy = 'pa_colour'
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term1
ON wp_tax1.term_id = wp_term1.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term2
ON wp_tax2.term_id = wp_term2.term_id
WHERE wp_vge8pp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND wp_vge8pp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_term1.name = 'dresses' /* DRESSES CATEGORY */
```

I get all the products that have the belong to the "dresses" category and that is the correct outcome.

**HOWEVER when I query both taxonomies together no products is returned:**

```
SELECT
wp_vge8pp_posts.post_title, wp_term2.term_id
FROM wp_vge8pp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_relationships
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_vge8pp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy wp_tax1
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_tax1.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_tax1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy wp_tax2
ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_tax2.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_tax2.taxonomy = 'pa_colour'
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term1
ON wp_tax1.term_id = wp_term1.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term2
ON wp_tax2.term_id = wp_term2.term_id
WHERE wp_vge8pp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND wp_vge8pp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_term2.name = 'green' /* GREEN COLOUR */
AND wp_term1.name = 'dresses' /* DRESSES CATEGORY */
```

How can I fix the query in order to get products that have *green* colour and belong to the *dresses* category?

**Note: If useful here is the DB structure for Woocommerce:** http://www.webhat.in/article/woocommerce-tutorial/how-product-attribute-are-stored-in-database/

Comment: Left join x... where x =... is the same as inner join x, so move conditions on left joined tables TO the Left join

Comment: What do you mean? can you send me the final query so I understand what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution after trying many different ways:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp1.post_title
FROM wp_vge8pp_posts wp1
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_relationships ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.object_id = wp1.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy wp_tax1 ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_tax1.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_tax1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term1 ON wp_tax1.term_id = wp_term1.term_id
WHERE wp1.post_type = 'product' AND wp1.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_term1.name = 'dresses'

AND EXISTS (

    SELECT wp2.post_title
    FROM wp_vge8pp_posts wp2
    LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_relationships ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.object_id = wp2.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy wp_tax2 ON wp_vge8pp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_tax2.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_tax2.taxonomy = 'pa_colour'
    LEFT JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term2 ON wp_tax2.term_id = wp_term2.term_id
    WHERE wp_term2.name = 'green'
    AND wp1.ID = wp2.ID

)
```

Basically I selected all the products with category 'Dresses' and then narrowed down by looking for the colour 'green'.

The trick to connect both categories was to reference the tables two times (giving them different names) and then connect them at the end by the post ID:

```
wp1.ID = wp2.ID
```

Also, I've added "DISTINCT" to make sure there are no repeated products on the results.

Comment: Cool. Seems like more query than is strictly necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.post_title
     , t2.term_id
  FROM wp_vge8pp_posts p
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_relationships tr
    ON tr.object_id = p.ID
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy tx1
    ON tx1.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
   AND tx1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' 

  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_vge8pp_term_taxonomy tx2
    ON tx2.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
   AND tx2.taxonomy = 'pa_colour' 

  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms t1
    ON t1.term_id = tx1.term_id 

    -- B

  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_vge8pp_terms wp_term2 t2
    ON t2.term_id = tx2.term_id  

    -- A

 WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
   AND p.post_status = 'publish'

   AND t2.name = 'green' /* GREEN COLOUR */        -- MOVE THIS LINE TO A
   AND t1.name = 'dresses' /* DRESSES CATEGORY */  -- AND THIS LINE TO B
```

If you're still struggling, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)